# Compare hex or binary to a table in R

Tags: r, binary, hex

I'd like to be compare binary or hexadecimal numbers to a range in R.

Specifically, I have hex codes of aircrafts (e.g. 4067F7) and I'd like to know which country that code is allocated to (e.g. UK). The country allocations are given as binary ranges.
cf. the table here: http://www.kloth.net/radio/icao24alloc.php

I figured that I can convert from hex to binary with hex2bin but after that I'm stuck as I can't figure out how to compare the binaries to the ranges.

Thanks!